# How can I use HSQLDB with Ruby on Rails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hsqldb

I want a use new databse with Rubey on rails.

That database is HSQLDB.

How can I use?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably to use JRuby, since HSQLDB is a Java Database.

Otherwise, try http://www.infoq.com/news/ruby-driver-hsqldb and http://rubyforge.org/projects/hypersonic/

You might also want to have a look at SQLite instead of HSQLDB, since they are similar, but SQLite is not written in Java.

From http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

`With the default page size of 1024 bytes, an SQLite database is limited in size to 2 terabytes (2^41 bytes). And even if it could handle larger databases, SQLite stores the entire database in a single disk file and many filesystems limit the maximum size of files to something less than this. So if you are contemplating databases of this magnitude, you would do well to consider using a client/server database engine that spreads its content across multiple disk files, and perhaps across multiple volumes.`

Read the rest of that page to see if it will suite your needs.

Two other pages you might find useful:
http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html
http://www.sqlite.org/mostdeployed.html

Comment: Thanks for replying but i want to create database for temperory storage. can u tell me what is a max capacity of sqlite for storing of data.& capacity diff between hsqldb & sqlite

Comment: I've updated my answer with some details on SQLite.  See the web site for more info.

Comment: Thank u so much & surely i will go through it

Comment: What u think about H2 database can i use it with ruby on rails

Comment: I don't really know anything about H2, but it is also written in Java.  You will likely be able to use it from Ruby running on Java.  i.e. JRuby.  If you don't want to use JRuby then a non-java database would probably be better.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on JRuby:

1- Download the hsqldb driver from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hsqldb/files/) and add the hsqldb.jar to your /lib

2- In your project's `config/database.yml` file:

```
...
development:
  database: db_name
  adapter: jdbc
  driver: org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
  schema: K12_EDUCATION
  url: jdbc:hsqldb:file:./db_files/db_name
```